# SQL: Cumulative count of rows up to including date, for multiple dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table of customer purchases in the following format:

```
---------------------------------------------
| customer_id | purchase_id | purchase_date |
---------------------------------------------
| 001         | 001         | 01-01-2018    |
| 001         | 002         | 02-01-2018    |
| 001         | 005         | 09-01-2018    |
| 002         | 003         | 04-01-2018    |
| 002         | 004         | 08-01-2018    |
| 002         | 006         | 10-01-2018    |
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a SQL query that counts the cumulative number of purchases by each customer for each day (i.e. how many rows does a customer have in the table with a purchase_date up to and including the date).

The desired output would be as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------
| customer_id | date        | # purchases |
-------------------------------------------
| 001         | 01-01-2018  | 1           |
| 001         | 02-01-2018  | 2           |
| 001         | 03-01-2018  | 2           |
| 001         | 04-01-2018  | 2           |
| 001         | 05-01-2018  | 2           |
| 001         | 06-01-2018  | 2           |
| 001         | 07-01-2018  | 2           |
| 001         | 08-01-2018  | 2           |
| 001         | 09-01-2018  | 3           |
| 001         | 10-01-2018  | 3           |
| 002         | 01-01-2018  | 0           |
| 002         | 02-01-2018  | 0           |
| 002         | 03-01-2018  | 0           |
| 002         | 04-01-2018  | 1           |
| 002         | 05-01-2018  | 1           |
| 002         | 06-01-2018  | 1           |
| 002         | 07-01-2018  | 1           |
| 002         | 08-01-2018  | 2           |
| 002         | 09-01-2018  | 2           |
| 002         | 10-01-2018  | 3           |
-------------------------------------------
```

What is the most efficient way to get this output?

Note: Running SQL Server 2016

Comment: Stack Overflow is a problem-solving site, not a coding service.  Show what  you've tried and what results you got and someone will help you figure out what (if anything) is wrong.  See [ask] and [mcve] for further details.

Comment: @Brian Meh, there are plenty of "code this for me" questions on SO. At least this one is clearly posed with sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below query using a Tally table approach for counting dates.
Also see <kbd>**[live demo](http://rextester.com/XIHYXY15497)**</kbd>

```
select 
    p.customer_id,
    d,
    count=count(*)
from
(select 
    customer_id,
    min=min(purchase_date),
    max=max(purchase_date)
from purchases
group by customer_id
)p -- p provides max min date ranges per customer id
cross apply
(
select top (datediff(d,min,max)+1)
d=dateadd(d,row_number() over (order by (select null))-1,min)
from
sys.objects s1 cross join
sys.objects s2
    )c --tally table part
left join
purchases p2
on p2.customer_id =p.customer_id
and d>=p2.purchase_date
group by p.customer_id,d
order by p.customer_id,d
```

Answer (score 2):

Window functions solve this problem quite nicely.

```
select customer_id, 
purchase_date, 
lead(purchase_date) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_id) as next_purchase,
count(*) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_id) as purchases
from purchases
order by customer_id,
purchase_date
```

This would output the result below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| customer_id | purchase_date | next_purchase | purchases   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 001         | 01-01-2018    | 02-01-2018    | 1           |
| 001         | 02-01-2018    | 09-01-2018    | 2           |
| 001         | 09-01-2018    | null          | 3           |
| 002         | 04-01-2018    | 08-01-2018    | 1           |
| 002         | 08-01-2018    | 10-01-2018    | 2           |
| 002         | 10-01-2018    | null          | 3           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want to fill in the gaps then use a CTE to generate a list of dates that you can join to. Based upon your desired output, I assume you want to report between the minimum and maximum dates in the purchases table. Also, I assume you're reporting on a monthly interval.

```
--Return First of Month for minimum and maximum purchase date since we're reporting by month
declare @start_date date = dateadd(m, -1, dateadd(d, 1, eomonth((select min(purchase_date) from purchases))));
declare @end_date date = dateadd(m, -1, dateadd(d, 1, eomonth((select max(purchase_date) from purchases))));

--Use recursive CTE to create stream of dates for each month between start and end date
with dates as (
    select @start_date as report_date
    union all
    select dateadd(m, 1, report_date)
    from dates
    where dateadd(m, 1, report_date) <= @end_date
)

select 
p.customer_id,
d.report_date,
p.purchases
from 
    (
        select customer_id, 
        purchase_date, 
        lead(purchase_date) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_id) as next_purchase,
        count(*) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_id) as purchases
        from purchases
        order by customer_id,
        purchase_date
    ) p
join dates d
    on d.report_date >= p.purchase_date
    and (d.report_date < p.next_purchase or d.next_purchase is null)
```

Final output:

```
---------------------------------------------
| customer_id | purchase_date | purchases   |
---------------------------------------------
| 001         | 01-01-2018    | 1           |
| 001         | 02-01-2018    | 2           |
| 001         | 03-01-2018    | 2           |
| 001         | 04-01-2018    | 2           |
| 001         | 05-01-2018    | 2           |
| 001         | 06-01-2018    | 2           |
| 001         | 07-01-2018    | 2           |
| 001         | 08-01-2018    | 2           |
| 001         | 09-01-2018    | 3           |
| 001         | 10-01-2018    | 3           |
| 002         | 04-01-2018    | 1           |
| 002         | 05-01-2018    | 1           |
| 002         | 06-01-2018    | 1           |
| 002         | 07-01-2018    | 1           |
| 002         | 08-01-2018    | 2           |
| 002         | 09-01-2018    | 2           |
| 002         | 10-01-2018    | 3           |
---------------------------------------------
```

The only difference between our output tables is that my method wont start showing customers until they've made at least one purchase. Also, this method assumes that your purchases table has 1 record per month per customer. Since that is unlikely, you should first group purchases by month.